# It it bad practice to use inheritance in database to make it less painful to change schema latter?

Tags: database, database-design, inheritance

I'm thinking on new design for database. And I want to use Table-Per-Type inheritance inside database. I want to separate audit data (like create|modify dates, user_id , permissions,etc) from actual data, and use some abstract objects(tables) but I don't plan to have deeper than 3 inheritance (to make things simple and fast). The reasons for this I want my database design to be flexible, and easy to modify, without lots of impact on my code. And using inheritance and extending existing functionality that way looks like a good choice to me.

I read some posts that using inheritance in database is bad practice, but I never seen explanation of that and what exact problems can occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an answer to my own question: I have reread Martin Fowler's book patterns of enterprise application architecture about database inheritance. And it helped me to clear my thought and choose my inheritance strategy. Nothing bad in using inheritance in database, and as S.Lott said, this requires thorough thinking and testing.

Answer (score 2):

> I want my database design to be flexible, and easy to modify, without lots of impact on my code.

First, you're just describing Object-Relational Mapping (ORM).  You need to update your question to specify a language, and a database and an ORM.

Second, this kind of flexibility is often an attractive nuisance.

You don't specify what database you're using, but there can be a fundamental contradiction in your desires.

A SQL database has a relatively fixed, less-than-perfectly-flexible schema so that it can be fast.

Asking for flexibility means you must now make certain kinds of relatively painful and complex changes to the database in the name of "flexibility".  Table design changes that involve moving (and possibly normalizing) data can be painful and difficult because the database isn't generally designed for flexibility.

More importantly, however, there's no simple mapping from inherited attributes to database tables.

There are times when superclass attributes should be copied into multiple tables.

However, there are also times when the superclass attributes should be a separate table with an explicit join to the subclass tables.

As you read more about ORM's, you'll see that this is a problem of non-trivial complexity.  It requires thinking, and each design decision has important consequences.

There is no "blanket" solution.  Your vague "And I want to use Table-Per-Type inheritance inside database" isn't a good idea or a bad idea.  It's a vague idea.  Each individual table and each individual inheritance decision must be made individually based on performance requirements and the expected need for flexibility.

Comment: @S.Lott: quote: "means you must now make certain kinds of relatively painful and complex changes to the database". Answer: No , I'm thinking on new database design, but I know that I will have to make lots of changes to it latter. I'm using 2 programming languages, C#, Java, and so 2 ORM tools, Hibernate and Nhibernate.

Comment: @Broken Pipe: "I know that I will have to make lots of changes to it latter."  These will be "painful and complex".  Any "structural" change; any change to normalization will be painful and complex because of the fixed SQL schema and the need to migrate data.

Comment: @S.Lott: I'm not planing to do radical structural schema changes like relationship changes, just adding new subtypes, adding|removing columns, changing datatypes. What I think is that with database type inheritance I will have to change less code.

Comment: @S.Loot:I don't understood your sentences about superclass attributes, what do you mean by attributes? (If it's class properties|Table Columns) I can't think of situation when I will need to have superclass properties be copied in subclass instead of referenced|inherited from superclass. (And I thought about it for some hours).

Comment: @Broken Pipe: "What I think is that with database type inheritance I will have to change less code".  Perhaps.  But you will have painful and difficult SQL changes to the database.

Comment: @Broken Pipe: "I can't think of situation when I will need to have superclass properties be copied in subclass".  Copied == no join to get the data.  You do this to prevent an expensive join operation.

Comment: @S.Lott: "You do this to prevent an expensive join operation." Join is not expensive, the speed of select from single table almost identical, to speed of select from joined tables with proper indexes (unless indexes are to large to fit in RAM, I haven't yet seen BD's with indexes consuming more than 2GB, and i don't plan my BD to consume insane amount of RAM that can't be installed on PC)

Comment: @Broken Pipe: "Join is not expensive".  Really?  Surprising.  Everyone else seems to think it involves more work than a single-table retrieval.  I guess everyone was wrong about that.  Odd to think that all these years every database designer has been wrong about the cost of a join and the impact of "denormalization" on performance.

Comment: @S.Lott: They were not wrong, it depends on database, but most modern RDBMS almost doesn't care about JOIN's if used properly. Mostly it's obsolete opinion. Here is test results showing singe table select and join on SQL Server 2008, with 200 000 rows. Results are identical, 1.17 and 1.24 sec, and it make perfect sense if you know how database indexes work. http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/8950/single.png http://img146.imageshack.us/img146/2148/joinr.png

Comment: @Broken Pipe: You can easily finesse SQL-only designs to achieve good performance.  Mapping this to your class structure requires careful thought and careful design.  You will not have "flexibility" if you want that kind of performance.  They are opposites.